# Singular or plural : Each + has/have + his/their

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

What is the correct use of pronoun with each/every/each of

- Each of the boys *has/have* brought *his/their* pen.
- Each boy *has/have* brought *his/their* pen.

Please explain which is correct pronoun here,  **his or their**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93860/discussion-on-question-by-pradeep-singular-or-plural-each-has-have-his-the).

Answer (score 1):

I would say in this particular example where we're talking about `boys`, in both cases,

> `each` is singular and therefore `has`/`his` is correct

However, today, in situations where (1) gender is unknown, (2) the group comprise both genders, or (3) there are gender-fluid individuals in the group, it has become more normal to adopt the *gender-neutral* `their` (and correspondingly `have`) instead of `his`.

> Each student should hand in **their** homework on time.
>
> Each and every employee is expected to submit **their** punch card.

Assuming the male gender as representative of everyone can at best be deemed an outdated notion from a bygone era, and at worst insensitive and offensive. Of course, we could say `his or her` but that sounds a little clumsy compared to `their`.

That said, in the original example, if it's fairly certain that the 'boys' do not have anyone who is gender-fluid in the group, we really should stick to `has/his`.

Answer (score 0):

"Each" requires a singular. Therefore the following are correct:

> - Each of the boys **has** brought **his** pen.
> - Each boy **has** brought **his** pen.